# Can I make a 3D scatter plot with words instead of numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot, valueerror

I'm doing a project for school and want to interpret this data in a 3d scatterplot but I keep getting "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Location'" when I run this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

df = pd.read_csv('baseball2.csv')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

x = ['Location']
y = ['Landing']
z = ['Speed']

ax.scatter(x, y, z)
ax.set_xlabel("Location")
ax.set_ylabel("Landing")
ax.set_zlabel("Speed")

plt.show()
```

Here is the CSV file it's not long:

```
Location, Landing, Speed,
1B, 3BF, 90,
1A, FLF, 93,
3B, 2B, 91,
2C, SRF, 92,
1C, P, 83,
2C, C, 85,
3A, FLF, 93,
2C, SRF, 84,
3A, SS, 93,
1C, CF, 92,
2B, FRF, 91,
3A, FLF, 90,
3A, FLF, 91,
1C, C, 91,
3A, C, 91,
2B, HR, 91,
2A, DRF, 92,
3B, SRF, 82,
1B, SCF, 82
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as a 3D scatter plot and use pseudo-numerical values for your categorical variables, but the resulting figure will be very difficult to read.  I recommend a 3D bar plot like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.gca(fc='white', projection='3d')

df = pd.read_csv('data_files/original_file.csv')
xy_data = [i for i in range(len(df[' Landing']))]

ax.bar3d(xy_data,xy_data, df[' Speed'],1,1, -df[' Speed'])
ax.set_xticklabels(df["Location"])
ax.set_yticklabels(df[" Landing"])

ax.set_xlabel("Location")
ax.set_ylabel("Landing")
ax.set_zlabel("Speed")
plt.show()
```

[image]

One last detail.  In your csv file, there is a leading whitespace before Landing and Speed in the header line. Keep that whitespace in mind when you call a dataframe column, as shown in my code.

**ADDENDUM**
In response to your comment, here is the code for a 3D scatter plot.  The xy_data list comprehension in both plots serves to create fake numerical values that are required for these types of graphs since they usually operate on continuous variables.  Your categorical variables are then assigned to these numerical placeholders by set_xticklabels() and set_yticklabels().

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.gca(fc='white', projection='3d')

df = pd.read_csv('data_files/original_file.csv')
xy_data = [i for i in range(len(df[' Landing']))]

ax.scatter3D(xy_data,xy_data, df[' Speed'], color = 'green')
ax.set_xticklabels(df["Location"])
ax.set_yticklabels(df[" Landing"])

ax.set_xlabel("Location")
ax.set_ylabel("Landing")
ax.set_zlabel("Speed")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but there is 1 problem, I cant point to a location on the graph whereas I could on a scatter plot. I'm very new to coding but how would I go about making the scatter plot? I plan on making the plot colored in a way the most repeated values stand out. Also what does the line "xy_data = [i for i in range(len(df[' Landing']))]" do?

Answer (score 0):

A scatter plot requires (x, y) coordinates, or other numerical location information.  Your question seems to be a contradiction in terms, since a string does not readily translate to a distance.

You have to define some metric for each label.  You could do this with a simple dict of lookup values.